Could not load file or assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=13.0.0.0, The system cannot find the file specified
In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I use these Nuget packages:
AutoMapper ver-12.0.1
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection ver-12.0.1

I removed:
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection ver-12.0.1

and upgraded AutoMapper to:
AutoMapper ver-13.0.1

However, I got this error:

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'AutoMapper, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005'
at AutoMapperServiceExtension.ConfigureAutoMappers(IServiceCollection services)
at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Program.cs:line 32

And it points to:
builder.Services.ConfigureAutoMappers()

Main code - extensions:
public static class AutoMapperServiceExtension
{
    public static void ConfigureAutoMappers(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(BankMapperProfile));
    }
}

Entity mapper:
public class BankMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public BankMapperProfile() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}       

Program.cs:
using API.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
var environment = builder.Environment;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(op => op.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
            = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddFluentValidation(options =>
    {
        options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    });

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

// Configure AutoMapper
builder.Services.ConfigureAutoMappers();

But I didn't use: AutoMapper, Version=13.0.0.0
Kindly help resolve the error

Does this answer your question? How to setup AutoMapper in ASP.Net Core 6

First Remove your Automapper package from your reference or un-install both AutoMapper ver-12.0.1 and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection ver-12.0.1
once you remove you should install it from "Package manager console", before install you need to select Project, It automatically installs the latest version.
No need to install  - AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection ver-12.0.1
Also, install - Microsft.Extension.DepedencyInjection
Install Automapper via package manager console
Add this service in your DI injection static class Add anyone, both working on the same process
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

or
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));

Add Service in Depedency class
Register your Automapper DI injection service in Program.cs
AutoMapper DI service registration in program.cs
Once complete this all build and run
